# Javascript and Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

My script works everywhere except in Internet Explorer. Actually no big deal.. but my debugger doesn't show any errors (Firebug Lite and the internal Explorer Debugger).

How can I find out which errors occur, if the debugger doesn't tell anything? Is there a documention for the JavaScript standard of Internet Explorer?

Comment: *Lots* of things can go wrong in IE. Your question does not have enough detail to be answareable.

Comment: Why don't you use a framework like jQuery?

Comment: and please also specify which version of internet explorer you're using

Comment: you can find lots of internet explorer specific javascript information at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533044.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no special documentation for that. 
I would advise you use a lot of `alert()` to see if every var gets the value you expect it to get.
One known isse for example is that if you have an event don't use the property `.target` on IE it will not work, use `.OriginalTarget`.

Comment: if by saying `There's no special documentation for that` if you where referring to the OP asking `Is there a documentation for the JavaScript standard of Internet Explorer`, then saying that is incorrect?, there is plenty of documentation on ie's proprietary browser features.

Answer (score 0):

There are thousands of different things this could be.  Since you've included no specific information at all in your question, there is no specific advice we can give you.

The general purpose way of solving an issue like this is to:

- Look for javascript errors in your debugging tools.
- Find a way to isolate what area of your javascript is responsible for the problem based on the symptoms and your knowledge of the code.
- Isolate approximately where in that piece of javascript the problem is (e.g. what function or what general method), either with console.log() statements to find where variables are not set to expected values or executing is not reaching or by stepping through that section of the code.
- Then, when you have a specific problem to ask about, post the relevant code and HTML and what versions of IE that it doesn't work in to ask a very specific question.  If you can, make a demonstrable example of the problem in jsfiddle.